# Why is g++ complaining?

Tags: c++, g++

Can somebody please explain this phenomenon?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {}
```

And compile it, gaves:

```
g++ main.cpp -Dn=1
<command-line>:0:3: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

And here is the complete [video](https://asciinema.org/a/XxsbBz0NnLI2OANcGQqC0Fa9c). I want to know the complete listing of these reserve thingy, and what they are. My environment is `cygwin`:

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: `iostream` distributed with your compiler uses `n` somewhere, and the only way to avoid it is not to `#define n` anywhere before including `<iostream>`.  `<iostream>` shouldn't do do that (since, in C++, `n` is not a reserved identifier) but if it does your only option is to avoid using that macro name. It is rare in C++ to *actually* need to define/use *any* macro, since there are alternatives that are usually considered preferable. So your first option is not to use macros. If you insist on using macros (usually not a smart call) then either use different names or use a different compiler.

Answer (score 7):

`-Dn=1` is defining `n` as a macro before `iostream` is included, which means it is redefining every occurrence of `n` in  `iostream` as 1, which breaks a lot of stuff.

To fix it, pick a different macro name, or move the `#define` to inside the file after the include.

Comment: Huh? And how are we to avoid these collisions? Great, that it gave a compile error. Else, no compile errors, and it changes the underlying c++ library behavior. Do you know where to find the complete listings of these thingy? I like to dynamically defined my macro values at compilation time.

Comment: " I like to dynamically defined my macro values at compilation time." 1 - use all uppercase letters identifiers 2 - use longer names

Comment: The only way to avoid collisions with macro substitutions is to not collide. Use better names and avoid macros.

Comment: @typelogic: yes, its a bug in the iostream library/header -- names that do not start with `_` or contain `__` and are not reserved by that library should be safe to use as macros.  Note that `n` *is* a reserved name in the `<random>` library, so that may be where it is coming from.  You can find all the reserved names in spec's "Index of library names"